# Importing a cropped area with FPDI

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, fpdi

I am creating a new PDF file by importing from an existing PDF, using FPDI.

```
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->setSourceFile("original.pdf");  
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
```

How can I import a specific region from the existing PDF onto the new PDF that I am creating?

I have the variables, for example:

```
$x=5; //My desired box begins 5cm from the left
$y=4; // ...and 4cm from the top
$w=4; // ...and is 4cm wide
$h=5; // ...and 5cm in height
```

How can I import this specific area?